# Out of all the proofs of the PNT, which one is the most accessible?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have been studying the continuation of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for the past while. I can prove that all the zeroes must lie in the critical strip.I am currently in the process of using this to prove the Prime Number Theorem. Of course I want to prove it analytically, and would like to know which proof would be best suited for somebody of an intermediate understanding of complex analysis and number theory.
I have had a look at Newmans proof, and see that it requires knowledge of laplace transform and his analytic theorem. Would understanding these concepts be less effort than proving the PNT by more 'traditional' means?

Comment: There are completely elementary proofs of the PNT, but I find them to be grungier and have less explanatory power than ones using advanced machinery. If you're interested in analytic number theory, you'll have to cover this stuff eventually; why not do it now, when you even have an immediate, compelling reason to do so?

Comment: Also, Newman's proof is designed (I believe) to avoid complex analysis as much as possible. So changing from Newman's proof to more traditional proofs is likely to require a bit more advanced mathematics. On the other hand, I find the big picture of the proof more sensible in that more advanced context - a "simple" application of the residue theorem/changing contours; plus, when taken to its logical extreme, it actually provides an explicit formula for $\pi(x)$ (or, more immediately, $\psi(x)$). So, do you want the technically simplest proof, or the most ultimately enlightening?

Comment: In these elementary methods, the zeta function is not important right? The reason for my interest in PNT is the zeta function and want to work from there.

Comment: Correct - the elementary proofs start from the Selberg identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Elementary_proofs), which doesn't require the zeta function to establish, and then proceed by similarly non-complex-analysis means.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks ,  if you were to suggest one of the traditional methods, which one would be best to look at? Do they all follow the same lines as the first proofs from De La Valeé Poussin and Hadamard?

Comment: Here is an interesting viewpoint: http://www.tricki.org/article/If_you_are_getting_stuck_then_try_to_prove_rigorously_that_your_approach_cannot_work#prime_number_theorem

Comment: the PNT is directly proved by $|\ln \zeta(1+it)| \ne \infty$ for $t \ne 0$ because it implies that the Dirichlet series for $\ln \zeta(s)$ when $\Re(s) \to 1^+$  has a dominant term $-\ln(s-1)$, and thus $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$. just apply some filtering to the Fourier transform $\frac{\ln \zeta(1+it)}{1+it}$ to see this !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the background of the proof of PNT and an elementary proof of i in this article http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf